# Rename column within function in r using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

In this case, I have a loop that triggers a function, which in turn triggers a function that collects the data.

One weird thing, is I cannot rename the columns in the dataset created - d. Bascially I need standardised names such that I can pass different variables, and as a result, I need to rename the columns during the dplyr transformation. The problem is here: %>% rename(Con = 1, DV = 2). In the dataset I have selected, I want to label the first column con, and the second column DV, such that I can pass this into the CollectDEffect function to run the cohensD analysis. All of this works when I run line by line, but I want to run the function by all the DVs and create a table, hence why I need to get this working within the loop.

```
# Function to run analyses and create the dataframe with output
CD_EE_DF <- data.frame("Test" = character())

CollectDEffect = function(cd, d){
  excess <- data.frame("Test" = cd, 
                       "Sample Size"  = nrow(d),
                       "Original Cohen's d" = cohensD(d$DV ~ d$Con))
  
  CD_EE_DF <- rbind(CD_EE_DF, excess)
  return(CD_EE_DF)
}

# Data transformation, where the error is
CollectDEffect_Trigger = function(DVTest){
  # Problem occurs here with the rename 
  d <- df %>%  filter(Gender == "Female", Target_Gender != "") %>% select(Target_Gender, DVTest) %>% rename(Con = 1, DV = 2) %>% na.omit()
  CD_EE_DF <- CollectDEffect(paste0("A_",DVTest),d) 
}

# Loop that triggers all of the analyses

vec_dv <- c("Status", "warmth")

for (DVTest in vec_dv) {
  CD_EE_DF <- CollectDEffect_Trigger(DVTest)
}
```

Comment: What is `vec_dv`? It is not defined in this example

Comment: Added, basically a vector of strings with the DV name

Comment: The reason your code crashes may have to do with the fact that you are passing `df` into the start of your pipeline on the problematic line.  

`df` is a function in the stats package.  

You may have also created a data.frame in the global environment called `df`, which could be causing your code to work line-by-line, but somehow not when running in the loop.  

Without knowing what `df` is, it's hard to help any more than that.